# How do I stop the Android Spotify Remote SDK from automatically disconnecting? (Flutter App)

Tags: android, flutter, spotify

Everytime I leave the app idle for a while, the spotify remote disconnects automatically.  I'm not sure if this is actually a thing or just with Flutter, but I need it to be running until I tell it to stop running.

This message gets thrown every time:

> Message from Spotify: [6,{"message":"App service
>   stopping"},"wamp.error.system_shutdown"]

Once I try to play again, the remote can't connect.  I've checked to see if the Spotify remote is null or if it is disconnected, but it looks like it's neither:

```
if (mSpotifyAppRemote == null) {
    System.out.println("[player state]: remote is null");
    activateSpotifyRemote(arguments);
} else if (!mSpotifyAppRemote.isConnected()) {
    System.out.println("[player state]: remote is not connected");
    activateSpotifyRemote(arguments);
} else {
    // always goes down to here, but nothing happens after message.
    handleSpotifyPlayerAPI(arguments);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'disconnects'? do you mean you lose your authentication to the api?

Comment: Essentially:   
D/RemoteServiceIo( 9890): stop remote client
D/RemoteServiceIo( 9890): Message from Spotify: [6,{"message":"App service stopping"},"wamp.error.system_shutdown"]   
Would it be possible to run the remote sdk on an Android service?